# how to view image on mvc website instantly after uploading?

Tags: html, .net, model-view-controller

I have website with form I'am uploading image from using Html.BeginForm() through the controller. Uploaded image saves correctly (i see it in folder) but I can't see it on website. To do so I have to reload entire webbrowser.
How can I make image showing on my website after uploading? Website shows this image few times, on different views, always by `<img scr="imagePatch"/>`. New image just saves itself with the same name as previous one, replacing it.

Comment: I know and I'm doing it, but after clicking on submit page reloads (because I'm using controller) and I see old one. Furthermore I need to view it on other subpages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to do this 
you can use html file api inside your form.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    // render the image in our view
    function renderImage(input,file) {

      // generate a new FileReader object
      var reader = new FileReader();

      // inject an image with the src url
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        the_url = event.target.result;
        $('.img-preview__').remove();
        $(input).after("<img class='img-preview__' src='" + the_url + "' />")
      }

      // when the file is read it triggers the onload event above.
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    // handle input changes  ... you can change selector
    $("#the-file-input").change(function(event) {
        // grab the first image in the FileList object and pass it to the function
        renderImage(event.target,this.files[0]);
    }); 
});
```

this will work nice . either you can make your image preview look like better.
for image preview element use this css code

```
 img.img-preview__ {
    width: 120px;
    border: 3px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

for example

```
<h2>Create</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Image", null, FormMethod.Post, 
                              new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Image</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="the-file-input" title="Upload a product image" 
                                  type="file" name="file" />
        </div>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

I hope this help

Comment: Works Perfect! "reader.readAsDataURL(" is worth remembering :)

Comment: Can I update images on other views as well? I mean to upload it on one and see new image on other pages? Image is saving itself correctly and in the same view it looks updated, but on other pages it is not.