# Refresh pdf with a new one at the same file name

Tags: c#, itext

I created a PDF using iTextSharp and to view the PDF I used an IFrame, I changed the PDF content but with the same file name (Test.pdf). But the IFrame still shows the first PDF (unchanged).

To solve this I deleted the browser cache, changed the file name and deleted all files with the name "Test" on our computer.

Using the code below the IFrame still shows the first PDF.

```
iframe1.Attributes["src"] = ("~/pdf/Test.pdf?var=" + 
                              DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"));
```

Comment: Could you please post a jsfiddle + the browser (+version) you use?

Comment: Have you restarted/cleared server cache if any? It might be that the server cached static file.

Comment: javascript has something like "readAsDataURL". This reads your "whatever" as new thing, no mather if it already is in browser cash or not, here is post about something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379970/how-to-view-image-on-mvc-website-instantly-after-uploading or with less text :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

Comment: Firefox 52.0.2 (32-bit)

Comment: This issue does not appear [tag:itext] related. If the file is successfully updated in the file system,  you should replace that tag by more appropriate ones. If it is not successfully updated,you should say so and post more information on the pdf generation code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some javascript:

```
var preview = document.querySelector('Place you want your pdf to be displayed');
var reader = new FileReader();
var PdfURL = 'address of your pdf';

reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
    preview.src = PdfURL;
  }, false);

if (preview) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(preview);
  }
```

Details can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL